# How can we tile a vector image?

Tags: android, vector-graphics

With the support library now fully supporting vector images, I'm trying to switch to vector images as much as I can in my app.
An issue I'm running into is that it seems impossible to repeat them.

With bitmap images the following xml could be used:

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/repeat_me"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    />
```

This does not work, as vector images can not be used in bitmaps:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187566

Is there any other way to tile/repeat vector images?

Comment: not directly, but you can `draw()` your `VectorDrawable` multiple times

Comment: Since vector images are scalable you would have to additionally specify the width/height before repeating. Also repeating manually (just display them several times) is surely an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check Nick Butcher solution: 
https://gist.github.com/nickbutcher/4179642450db266f0a33837f2622ace3 
Add TileDrawable class to your project and then set tiled drawable to your image view:

```
// after view created
val d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pattern)
imageView.setImageDrawable(TileDrawable(d, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT))
```

Comment: Answers shouldn't be mainly a link - which can be taken offline or change.

Comment: While Nick Butcher's solution does work, it has a potential memory utilization problem, depending on how you're using the TileDrawable since it requires rendering the child Drawable to a Bitmap every time a new TileDrawable is created.

Answer (score 8):

This is the java version of Nick Butcher solution:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class TileDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final Paint paint;

    public TileDrawable(Drawable drawable, Shader.TileMode tileMode) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(getBitmap(drawable), tileMode, tileMode));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

You can use this drawable class in code with vector patterns:

```
view.setBackground(new TileDrawable(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.pattern), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @pskink I made a drawable that tiles another drawable:
https://gist.github.com/9ffbdf01478e36194f8f

This has to be set in code, it can not be used from XML:

```
public class TilingDrawable extends android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper {

    private boolean callbackEnabled = true;

    public TilingDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        callbackEnabled = false;
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = getWrappedDrawable();

        int width = wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        for (int x = bounds.left; x < bounds.right + width - 1; x+= width) {
            for (int y = bounds.top; y < bounds.bottom + height - 1; y += height) {
                wrappedDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
                wrappedDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
        callbackEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        if (callbackEnabled) {
            super.invalidateDrawable(who);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
        if (callbackEnabled) {
            super.scheduleDrawable(who, what, when);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
        if (callbackEnabled) {
            super.unscheduleDrawable(who, what);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has a lot of warnings that you shouldn't call those functions on your own, because your code is not a part of the support library. Is there an alternative way to write it, which doesn't use hidden API ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to put a full solution that doesn't require the support library hidden class, written in Kotlin, based on what was suggested in one of the answers ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36060157/878126)) :

**DrawableWrapper.kt**

```
open class DrawableWrapper(drawable: Drawable) : Drawable(), Drawable.Callback {
    var wrappedDrawable: Drawable = drawable
        set(drawable) {
            field.callback = null
            field = drawable
            drawable.callback = this
        }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) = wrappedDrawable.draw(canvas)

    override fun onBoundsChange(bounds: Rect) {
        wrappedDrawable.bounds = bounds
    }

    override fun setChangingConfigurations(configs: Int) {
        wrappedDrawable.changingConfigurations = configs
    }

    override fun getChangingConfigurations() = wrappedDrawable.changingConfigurations

    override fun setDither(dither: Boolean) = wrappedDrawable.setDither(dither)

    override fun setFilterBitmap(filter: Boolean) {
        wrappedDrawable.isFilterBitmap = filter
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        wrappedDrawable.alpha = alpha
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(cf: ColorFilter?) {
        wrappedDrawable.colorFilter = cf
    }

    override fun isStateful() = wrappedDrawable.isStateful

    override fun setState(stateSet: IntArray) = wrappedDrawable.setState(stateSet)

    override fun getState() = wrappedDrawable.state


    override fun jumpToCurrentState() = DrawableCompat.jumpToCurrentState(wrappedDrawable)

    override fun getCurrent() = wrappedDrawable.current

    override fun setVisible(visible: Boolean, restart: Boolean) = super.setVisible(visible, restart) || wrappedDrawable.setVisible(visible, restart)

    override fun getOpacity() = wrappedDrawable.opacity

    override fun getTransparentRegion() = wrappedDrawable.transparentRegion

    override fun getIntrinsicWidth() = wrappedDrawable.intrinsicWidth

    override fun getIntrinsicHeight() = wrappedDrawable.intrinsicHeight

    override fun getMinimumWidth() = wrappedDrawable.minimumWidth

    override fun getMinimumHeight() = wrappedDrawable.minimumHeight

    override fun getPadding(padding: Rect) = wrappedDrawable.getPadding(padding)

    override fun invalidateDrawable(who: Drawable) = invalidateSelf()

    override fun scheduleDrawable(who: Drawable, what: Runnable, `when`: Long) = scheduleSelf(what, `when`)

    override fun unscheduleDrawable(who: Drawable, what: Runnable) = unscheduleSelf(what)

    override fun onLevelChange(level: Int) = wrappedDrawable.setLevel(level)

    override fun setAutoMirrored(mirrored: Boolean) = DrawableCompat.setAutoMirrored(wrappedDrawable, mirrored)

    override fun isAutoMirrored() = DrawableCompat.isAutoMirrored(wrappedDrawable)

    override fun setTint(tint: Int) = DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, tint)

    override fun setTintList(tint: ColorStateList?) = DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, tint)

    override fun setTintMode(tintMode: PorterDuff.Mode) = DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrappedDrawable, tintMode)

    override fun setHotspot(x: Float, y: Float) = DrawableCompat.setHotspot(wrappedDrawable, x, y)

    override fun setHotspotBounds(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) = DrawableCompat.setHotspotBounds(wrappedDrawable, left, top, right, bottom)
}
```

**TilingDrawable.kt**

```
class TilingDrawable(drawable: Drawable) : DrawableWrapper(drawable) {
    private var callbackEnabled = true

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        callbackEnabled = false
        val bounds = bounds
        val width = wrappedDrawable.intrinsicWidth
        val height = wrappedDrawable.intrinsicHeight
        var x = bounds.left
        while (x < bounds.right + width - 1) {
            var y = bounds.top
            while (y < bounds.bottom + height - 1) {
                wrappedDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height)
                wrappedDrawable.draw(canvas)
                y += height
            }
            x += width
        }
        callbackEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onBoundsChange(bounds: Rect) {}

    override fun invalidateDrawable(who: Drawable) {
        if (callbackEnabled)
            super.invalidateDrawable(who)
    }

    override fun scheduleDrawable(who: Drawable, what: Runnable, `when`: Long) {
        if (callbackEnabled)
            super.scheduleDrawable(who, what, `when`)
    }

    override fun unscheduleDrawable(who: Drawable, what: Runnable) {
        if (callbackEnabled)
            super.unscheduleDrawable(who, what)
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
yourView.background = TilingDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable)!!)
```

Comment: This solution has one very big improvement over the Nick Butcher solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621285/3032) -- this solution uses significantly less memory in certain use cases, since it does not require rendering the child Drawable to a Bitmap before drawing to the screen.

Comment: I modified the TilingDrawable to also override `getIntrinsicHeight()` and `getIntrinsicWidth()` to both return `-1` which gave me the results I was hoping for when setting this on an ImageView (e.g. as a placeholder). This drawable doesn't really have an intrinsic size, since it will scale to any size, and the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#getIntrinsicHeight()) indicate `-1` for these cases.

Comment: I don't understand. In some cases you mean that this code doesn't work? Can you please share ? Maybe I should change the answer?

Comment: I was struggling, because the code as written in this answer was not providing the desired results when setting the TilingDrawable on an ImageView (i.e. with `setImageDrawable()`) unless the ImageView's scaleType was set to fitXY. By adding in the `-1` for intrinsic width/height, I got the desired results.

Answer (score -1):

I see 2 easy workarounds to this problem:

**1.** To create (repeat) pattern you want in SVG manipulative software like 'Inkscape' or 'CorelDraw'. And then use this 'created_manually_pattern_svg' in your 'ImageView' as

```
... 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/created_manually_pattern_svg"
...
```

or even

```
...
android:background="@drawable/created_manually_pattern_svg"
...
```

in any ather 'view' (but i'm not sure if it works in all API levels)

**2.** Export your '.svg' file into '.png' and then use 'bitmap'.