# tileMode repeat with vector drawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

We can have a repeat drawable by using `tileMode="repeat"`

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/some_png"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

It only works if the drawable is a bitmap.

Is there any similar way to repeat a vector drawable?

Comment: No Drawable other than `bitmap` has the `tileMode` attribute.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057597/how-can-we-tile-a-vector-image